Problems with FC630 and FD332
We have acquired a new FD332 and now we use one FD332 for each FC630.
But I'm not able to configure the RAID, the disks are in foreign state and when accessing the configuration management I receive the message: "Unable to display menu options as there is no operation possible at this time".
Besides, in iDRAC I can see all the disks, but directly on the controller one disk is not displayed.
Where can I start?
Thank you.


